# CSS Animation on jQuery attribute change

Tags: jquery, css

I have an image container which is basically in a laptop shell. I'm trying to animate the screenshot on the laptop (slide left/right) every time the src changes

HTML

```
 <img class="img-responsive laptop-screen" src="img-container/demo-laptop.png">
```

jQuery function

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(".laptop-screen").attr("src", newsrc);
});
```

The src changes on click, but the new image just pops up immediately. Is there any way I can slide it in **without** having to create multiple img tags with `display:none;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#9f75750659b0d82a63bb885b17058c98

You can actually do the animation in Pure CSS without JavaScript. All I'm using JavaScript for in this case is to toggle a class and the image source.

```js
var changeIMG = document.querySelector(".changeIMG")
var oldSrc = 'http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02223/bear-cub-toy_2223075k.jpg'
var newSrc = 'http://image.mlive.com/home/mlive-media/width960/img/grandrapidspress/photo/2015/03/20/-6328b3da95a15820.JPG'

function changeSrc() {
  var imgElement = document.querySelector(".laptop-screen")
  var src = imgElement.src

  imgElement.src = src === oldSrc ? newSrc : oldSrc
  
  $('.laptop-screen').toggleClass('loaded preload')
}

changeIMG.onclick = function() {
  changeSrc()
}
changeSrc()
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  margin: auto;
}

.changeIMG {
  display: block;
}

.loaded, .preload {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  margin: 1.1em auto 0 auto;
}
.loaded {
  animation: scale .3s normal forwards;
}
.preload {
  animation: scaleIMG .3s normal forwards;
}

@keyframes scale {
  to {
    width: 52%;
  }
}
@keyframes scaleIMG {
  to {
    width: 52%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn changeIMG btn-primary">
  Change Source
</button>

<img class="loaded laptop-screen">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.load(fn)`:

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var newsrc = 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/browsers/Chrome.png';
  $(".laptop-screen").hide().attr("src", newsrc).load(function() {
    $(this).slideDown();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#'>change the image.</a><br>
<img class='laptop-screen' src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/browsers/IE.png' alt=''>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(".laptop-screen").hide('slide').attr("src", newsrc).show('slide');
});
```

if you didn't notice the slide .. may be you need to include jquery-ui